# No space left on device on AWS S3 tomcat 8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using the following code to write to S3 bucket which has lots of xml files now. I am getting a No space left on device error. The subsequent uploads are failing. I see lots of files getting created in var/cache/tomcat8/temp folder. I am deleting the files through my code. Can someone please help me out in understanding what is wrong here?  Actually we want to delete the temp file as soon as we upload it to S3.

```
Path path = Files.createTempFile(filename, suffix);
file = path.toFile();

Files.write(path, incomingXml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

if(file!=null){
    file.deleteOnExit();
}
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(fullBucketPathByDate, filename, file));
LOGGER.info("Upload completed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `File.deleteOnExit` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) (emphasis mine):

> Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname
>   be deleted **when the virtual machine terminates**.

That means that the temp file would only be deleted once you shutdown your Tomcat process. What you need to do is delete the file as soon as you are finished uploading it to S3. Something like this:

```
Path path = Files.createTempFile(filename, suffix);
file = path.toFile();

Files.write(path, incomingXml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

if(file!=null){
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(fullBucketPathByDate, filename, file));
    file.delete();
}
LOGGER.info("Upload completed");
```

Alternatively, look into streaming the file contents directly to S3 without using temp files at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help!